# How to scaffold EF core to existing DB?

Tags: ef-code-first, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to reverse engineer an existing database using `Entity Framework Core`. I tried to follow the directions [from Microsoft](https://ef.readthedocs.org/en/latest/platforms/aspnetcore/existing-db.html#reverse-engineer-your-model) but I am presented with the error:

> Unable to find provider assembly with name EntityFramework. Ensure the specified name is correct and is referenced by the project.

I am running the following command from the project directory:

```
dnx ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=REMOVED;Database=REMOVED;User ID=REMOVED;Password=REMOVED" EntityFramework
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you are in the project folder and not the solution folder context. I was able to get this to work with the following yesterday (Notice the EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer at the end)

```
dnx ef dbcontext scaffold "{connectionString}" EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer
```

EDIT:

Make sure to include the following in your project.json:

```
EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer.Design
```

Comment: I get the same error when I change from ending `EntityFramework` to `EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer` The solution does have 3 projects (CORE, DAL, WebUI) and I am in the WebUI project which does have `EntityFramework.Commands` and `EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer` in the project.json file

Comment: That reminded me, I also had to add this into my project.json:
EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer.Design

Comment: Adding that to the project.json fixed it. Thanks

Comment: installing EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer.Design did it

Answer (score 27):

Install fallowing NuGet package:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```

Answer (score 6):

I was getting the following error when trying to scaffold from an existing SQLite database:

```
Unable to find provider assembly with name Microsoft.EntityFramworkCore.Sqlite. Ensure the specified name is correct and is referenced by the project.
```

The project was in a solution with one other project.  Even though the correct project was referenced in the Package Manager Console it only worked when I selected the 'Set as Startup Project' item on the project context menu.

Comment: No luck on this option :(

Answer (score 1):

Close Visual Studio
Delete `%temp%` folder 
Delete `.vs` folder

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=REMOVED;Database=REMOVED;User ID=REMOVED;Password=REMOVED" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Install Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer from Nuget
2. In PM set the default project to the project that will contain the Models folder, then in PM...

```
PM> Scaffold-DbContext "Server=YOURSERVER;database=YOURDB;Trusted_Connection=True;" MicrosoftEntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -force
```